# My computer boots but shows nothing but a black display

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, black-screen-of-death

I am running Windows 7. My computer is booting and I can see the Welcome screen. However after this it just goes blank. I can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> and open up and see task manager. But the desktop does not show at all. Pressing <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> does not open the run window. In safe mode also I have the same problem. I can't see the desktop anywhere. However there is a mouse pointer which I can move around.

[image]

I tried http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/why-is-my-screen-black-when-i-start-windows-7. However when I create a new task it keeps crashing saying windows task manager has stopped working.

I tried to repair the computer however it tell me that it cannot do it.

Comment: Try unplugging every display except the monitor. My video card will default to using my TVs HDMI port instead of my monitor DVI port as the default display until I get the driver installed and configured.

Comment: may run `cmd` at task manager?

Comment: I can get access to cmd by booting into safe mode with cmd. I can also access regedit. However if I try to start explorer.exe it crashes. Is there any way I can roll back the driver updates using the tools I have access to right now?

Comment: @krowe I tried. It doesnt show anything on the HDMI port. I can only see the boot on the computer adapter

Comment: Can you get a context menu to come up, by doing a right-click with the cursor somewhere on the desktop?